# Is there a way to query and find out the version of Vertica installed?

Tags: sql, version, vertica

I searched the Vertica documentation for the keywords *Version* and *Version Number*. 
But I couldn't really get any mention of SQL query to select the version of Vertica installed. 
I thought there would be some system table that had some version information but couldn't find any.

Is it not possible to get the version of Vertica installed using an SQL query?
Or is it only possible to access version by logging into the Vertica host and checking some directory?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It can be found here: https://www.vertica.com/docs/latest/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Diagnostics/DeterminingYourVersionOfVertica.htm

```
db=> SELECT VERSION();
              VERSION
------------------------------------
 Vertica Analytic Database v9.1.0-2
(1 row)
```

Edit from the comments: hopefully a link to a permanent page, which will not become obsolete when new versions come: https://www.vertica.com/blog/version-vertica-running/

Comment: Newer link (that one will probably rot eventually): [version 8.1.x](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/SysInfo/VERSION.htm).

Comment: And another link.  This one looks like it will stay fresh: [https://www.vertica.com/blog/version-vertica-running/](https://www.vertica.com/blog/version-vertica-running/)

Answer (score 0):

Run below Query:

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

Sample Output:

```
Vertica Analytic Database v9.0.1-9
```